# Change from iterative to recursive method

Tags: c#

```
int arraySum (int [] a, int n) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    n = a.size();
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        sum += a[i];

    return sum; 
}
```

I want to convert this code from iterative to recursive.

Comment: Which language do you actually care about? Please edit your tags to *one* question. Also show what you've done to *try* to make it recursive - have you got *some* code, even if it doesn't work yet?

Comment: There's no point passing `n` when you then set `n` to `a.size()`

Comment: I assume this must be C# since that's the only one that has this as valid array syntax.

Comment: stackoverflow not for home work

Comment: Now is *really* the time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

C# Version:

```
int arraySum ( int [] a, int sum = 0, int i = 0 ) /*i = 0, technically means this code is logically different from yours, however it will count every element and is just a default :)*/
{
    if( i < a.Length )
        return arraySum( a, sum + a[i], ++i ); 
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: While the algorithm is tail-recursive, please keep in mind that C# does not support or optimize for tail-recursion. Therefore the method will throw a stack overflow exception for sufficiently big arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

1- Recursive definition like: `sum(n) = n + sum(n-1)`

2- You need to specify where should you stop so the recursion does not last forever.

for example: `if (n == 0) return 0;`

based on this you can code at any language.

C++ Example:

```
int arraySum (int a[], int n)
{
    if(n==1)
        return a[n-1];
    else
        return a[n-1] + arraySum (a, n-1);
}
```